# Spring boot mongo db error

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, restful-architecture

trying to connect to mongo db (mlab) in Spring Boot application. I have the following connection details.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<un>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/test
```

Application deploys successfully but when I hit the service, I am always getting below error:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "<XXXXX>/23.20.156.77:XXXXX" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
```

when I add below at the end of connection uri, Application fails deployment saying "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported authMechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1". Appreciate your help

```
authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Following is the dependency in my POM file

```
<!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What is your mongo shell server version ?

Comment: @Veeram what do you mean by shell version? I am using free mongo db from mlab

Comment: Can you log into mlab and see what mongo version it uses ? http://docs.mlab.com/ops/#available-versions

Comment: 3.2.x as per the docs you provided as my plan type is sandbox (free)